# Android layout with multiple scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to implement a layout which is split in 2 parts. The top part may contain a textview which needs to be able to scroll, the bottom part contains a textview and if that one extends the screen I want the entire screen to scroll.

This is what I have so far :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Text" />
            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sapien est, iaculis sed sodales at, tempus quis dui. Vivamus sem lacus, blandit et facilisis quis, interdum sed risus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nullam erat turpis, tristique id velit non, lacinia gravida dui. Vestibulum at sodales odio, vitae cursus nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut placerat orci et urna fermentum consectetur. Cras ut feugiat sem. Ut vitae quam diam. Suspendisse eget ante quis sem pretium commodo. Sed blandit sollicitudin imperdiet. Suspendisse eget purus auctor, accumsan magna vitae, elementum metus. Maecenas iaculis eget odio eu volutpat. Nunc tincidunt tellus vel turpis imperdiet, sit amet dapibus lacus pretium. Ut porttitor risus mattis molestie vestibulum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sapien est, iaculis sed sodales at, tempus quis dui. Vivamus sem lacus, blandit et facilisis quis, interdum sed risus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nullam erat turpis, tristique id velit non, lacinia gravida dui. Vestibulum at sodales odio, vitae cursus nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut placerat orci et urna fermentum consectetur. Cras ut feugiat sem. Ut vitae quam diam. Suspendisse eget ante quis sem pretium commodo. Sed blandit sollicitudin imperdiet. Suspendisse eget purus auctor, accumsan magna vitae, elementum metus. Maecenas iaculis eget odio eu volutpat. Nunc tincidunt tellus vel turpis imperdiet, sit amet dapibus lacus pretium. Ut porttitor risus mattis molestie vestibulum."/>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sapien est, iaculis sed sodales at, tempus quis dui. Vivamus sem lacus, blandit et facilisis quis, interdum sed risus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nullam erat turpis, tristique id velit non, lacinia gravida dui. Vestibulum at sodales odio, vitae cursus nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut placerat orci et urna fermentum consectetur. Cras ut feugiat sem. Ut vitae quam diam. Suspendisse eget ante quis sem pretium commodo. Sed blandit sollicitudin imperdiet. Suspendisse eget purus auctor, accumsan magna vitae, elementum metus. Maecenas iaculis eget odio eu volutpat. Nunc tincidunt tellus vel turpis imperdiet, sit amet dapibus lacus pretium. Ut porttitor risus mattis molestie vestibulum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sapien est, iaculis sed sodales at, tempus quis dui. Vivamus sem lacus, blandit et facilisis quis, interdum sed risus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nullam erat turpis, tristique id velit non, lacinia gravida dui. Vestibulum at sodales odio, vitae cursus nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut placerat orci et urna fermentum consectetur. Cras ut feugiat sem. Ut vitae quam diam. Suspendisse eget ante quis sem pretium commodo. Sed blandit sollicitudin imperdiet. Suspendisse eget purus auctor, accumsan magna vitae, elementum metus. Maecenas iaculis eget odio eu volutpat. Nunc tincidunt tellus vel turpis imperdiet, sit amet dapibus lacus pretium. Ut porttitor risus mattis molestie vestibulum."/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The resulting layout looks like this 
[layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9S2G.png)

This doesnt quite work as I would like it to. What am I missing ?

Comment: **1** A scrollable View inside another one is a worst practice. **2** Layout nesting is bad for performances.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a scrollable view within another one without doing some work with touch listeners. By default this won't work properly b/c the system doesn't know which scroll view to pass the touch events to.

You can write a touch listener that will lock one of the scroll views and pass touch events to the other one. This is similar to implementing pull to refresh on a recycler/list view. At position 0 activate the pull-to-refresh, and at any other position lock the pull-to-refresh.

Comment: That is good to know, but my question was more along the lines of why my layout doesnt display like i want it to. The top scrollview just displays the full textview instead of "cropping" it